# Iniciando em Lisp

Tags: lisp

Como começar em Lisp? Common Lisp para ser mais exato, é uma linguagem totalmente diferente do que estou acostumado (Só tenho 3 anos de estudo de programação), os exemplos de instalação que vi normalmente são em consoles, não consigo entender nada do que estão fazendo. Gostaria de ajuda para preparar a máquina para desenvolver em Lisp, o mais próximo que achei de uma IDE foi o CLisp, mas não sei como baixar, configurar e nem sei ao certo o que é.

Comment: Ler as informações da tag vai de dar uma boa ajuda. Como uma colher de chá: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/lisp/info

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado preciso de algo mais técnico, o geral da linguagem eu consegui achar, preciso de algo como uma IDE, instalação, essas coisas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como em qualquer linguagem, para começar você só precisa de um editor e um compilador/intepretador (pode ser o clisp).

Por exemplo, crie um arquivo e salve com o nome `meu_programa.lisp`, com o conteúdo:

```
; programa em lisp olá mundo
(print "Olá mundo")
```

No terminal:

```
$ clisp meu_programa.lisp

"Olá mundo"
```

Você instala ele pelo gerenciador de pacotes do seu S.O. ou baixando em https://clisp.sourceforge.io